# SharedElementTransition in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I am trying to perform a SharedElementTransition from an item in RecyclerView to an DetailedActivity for that element, but the transition is not shown, as well as on pressing the back button, the app crashes with the logcat as below:

> 06-24 16:03:52.512 31808-31808/com.example.xyzreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.example.xyzreader, PID: 31808
>                                                                          Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
>                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for MaxWidthLinearLayout
>                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5471)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

The various classes and layout files are as follow:

**ArticleListActivity.java**

```
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                    Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions
                            .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                                    activity,
                                    vh.titleView,
                                    vh.titleView.getTransitionName()
                            ).toBundle();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ItemsContract.Items.buildItemUri(getItemId(vh.getAdapterPosition())));

                    startActivity(intent, bundle);
                } else {

                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            ItemsContract.Items.buildItemUri(getItemId(vh.getAdapterPosition()))));
                }
```

**list_item_article.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
android:elevation="2dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:background="@color/my_image_background_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:transitionName="@string/shared_element_transition"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_title_cardview"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:transitionName="@string/article_title"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#6000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#6000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_article_detail.xml**

```
<com.example.xyzreader.ui.DrawInsetsFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/draw_insets_frame_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.xyzreader.ui.ObservableScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/photo_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.example.xyzreader.ui.ThreeTwoImageView
                android:id="@+id/photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:transitionName="@string/shared_element_transition" />


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="112dp"
                android:background="@drawable/photo_background_protection" />

        </FrameLayout>


        <com.example.xyzreader.ui.MaxWidthLinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photo_container"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/detail_card_max_width"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/meta_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/detail_metabar_vert_padding"
                android:background="#333"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/detail_metabar_vert_padding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/detail_inner_horiz_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/detail_inner_horiz_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/detail_metabar_vert_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/article_title"
                    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.9"
                    android:transitionName="@string/article_title"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/detail_metabar_title_bottom_padding"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/detail_title_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/article_byline"
                    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#8fff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_body"
                style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/detail_inner_horiz_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/detail_inner_horiz_margin"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="@fraction/detail_body_line_spacing_multiplier"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/detail_body_bottom_margin"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textColorLink="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/detail_body_text_size" />

        </com.example.xyzreader.ui.MaxWidthLinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</com.example.xyzreader.ui.ObservableScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/share_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_share"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
    app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a full stack trace? I think there should be something above the stack trace you posted.

I had a similar problem and I solved it by adding to the receiving xml a following attribute:

```
android:transitionGroup="true"
```

It was crashing in my case because an incoming view was too large.

Comment: I have already tried adding that in previous attempts, but to no avail! As far as the stack trace is concerned, it's the same as above, nothing specious above that.

Comment: Send me a link to your github and I'll look into it.

Comment: Were you able to come up with anything? @Dmytro Karataiev

Comment: It's working without crashes on my phone (Nexus 6P).

Comment: Is the shared transition working? It was crashing on back press for me.

Comment: I've recorded you a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpgEOsuihUM&feature=youtu.be